# Should I include a bibliographical entry in the Works Cited pages for works I just mention?

Tags: research-process, citations, writing

Should I include a bibliographical entry in the Works Cited pages for works I just mention?

For example, if I mention the work of an author by title just as an example without quoting from it, should I include an entry for it in the Works Cited page?

Comment: As opposed to what?

Comment: To put JeffE's comment a little more directly: Yes, of course.

Comment: If you mean by "as opposed to what?" what is the other alternative, then I mean mention the work in the text without including it in the Works Cited page.

Comment: @xLeitix: Not sure if it's a duplicate, perhaps the OP refers to the practice of putting the full reference in a footnote rather than as an entry in the biblio section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A bibliographical entry allows readers to unambiguously identify and locate the work you mention. (Which they must be able to do if they would like to verify your claims about this work.)